# How is this happening?

Tags: c, microcontroller, type-conversion

I am using an 8-bit Microcontroller. And this is the calculation that i want it to do:

```
unsigned int Vin_kl30 = 0;
unsigned int val_kl30; // val_kl30 gets the value from ADC.
int Vref = 5;   
Vin_kl30 = (unsigned int) val_kl30 * Vref; // this returns 12190
Vin_kl30 =   Vin_kl30 * 100; // expected value: 1219000 but i get 39852 ???
temp_kl30 = Vin_kl30;
```

Why does it happen this way? how can change this?

Comment: I could explain 39352, but 48350 sure looks like a bug.

Comment: @DanielFischer Perhaps you should explain 39352 anyway, I'd like to know why it could be anything other than 12190.

Comment: @DanielFischer: MY MISTAKE. 39852 it is. I will update the question.

Comment: @weston 16-bit `int` and `unsigned int`. `1219000 % 65536 = 39352`.

Comment: @sheetansh Still not explainable, 39352 would be the correct result for 16-bit `unsigned int`.

Comment: Ah, simple as that, btw, the question is still wrong sheetansh.

Comment: @DanielFischer: i edited the question again.

Comment: @sheetansh Now you have 39852, but 39352 would be the explainable value, which is it?

Comment: @DanielFischer: but why 65536? why modulus? i am just attempting to multiply it by 100.

Comment: But you are overflowing a 16 bit value, so you only get the 16 least significant bits in the result. So... 1219000 % 0xFFFF

Comment: @DanielFischer: it was 39852. not it changed to 40352. SO I AM ALL THE MORE CONFUSED. I am using CODEWARRIOR ver. 5.0.

Comment: @KScottPiel: so i should write this: Vin_kl30 = Vin_kl30 << 8; ??

Comment: @sheetansh No, you need a larger type to get 1219000, use `unsigned long` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb and assume the value you get is in fact

```
39352
```

That is the correct result for 16-bit wide `unsigned int`.

The arithmetic on unsigned integer types is specified to be arithmetic modulo `2^N` where `N` is the number of value bits in the type, or its *width*.

```
1219000 = 18*(2^16) + 39352
```

and with 16-bit wide `unsigned int`, the result is the remainder of the mathematical result, reduced modulo `2^16 = 65536`.

The other mentioned values, 48350, 39852, 40352 would all mean that the compiler violates the standard, since the difference between the mathematical result 1219000 and any of them is not a multiple of `2^16`, and the smallest allowed value for `UINT_MAX` is `2^16 - 1`, which means that `unsigned int` *must* be at least 16 bits wide.

Comment: Thanks for your mathematical imput. I understand how it works now. So i am gonna stick to unsigned long now. But wont close the question as of now as this is just one part of the bigger problem. THanks a lot daniel!!!